# How to deploy a standalone CherryPy process?

Tags: python, web-applications, cherrypy

I'm currently preparing to deploy a stand-alone CherryPy app. While I *could* just hack together a boot script and shoehorn it into the system's startup sequence, I'd rather find a more elegant solution.

What I need to do is:

- Start the app as a daemon during boot
- Restart it if it crashes
- Monitor CPU/memory usage

I'm sure there must be an existing solution for this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Specific to cherrypy, it has daemonizer and pidfile plugins.  And the [cherryd](http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/deployguide/cherryd.html) script supports them as command-line options.

More generally, [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) and [supervisord](http://supervisord.org) are popular choices for process monitoring.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12156434).